# Simple script sending data to server

Tags: bash, curl

I wanted to ask if my bash script is right. I want to send the output of the `sensors` command every 1 second, for 10 times:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..10}
do
a=$(date '+%s')
D=$(sensors)

curl -i -k -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{ "id":2,"timestamp":echo "${a}","data":echo "${D}"}' https://dv7knsjzph.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/prod/boxtronic-devices/2/data/
sleep 1
done
```

Thank you

Comment: You are missing `done` at the end of the script.

Comment: Yes I added it but I wanted to ask if the syntax is right. I want to upload the content of a and D every second to my server. Is  for example `"timestamp": "echo "${a}" ` or `"timestamp": echo "${a}"  `the right syntax

Comment: I think you should delete `echo`.

Comment: can you write an example of the syntaxe ? which one of the two.
Try it out of the script. deleting it prints an incomplete output

Comment: curl -i -k -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{ \"id\":2,\"timestamp\": \"${a}\",\"data\": \"${D}\"}" https:......

Comment: I think the correct would be `'{ "id":2,"timestamp": "'${a}'","data": "'${D}'"}'`, and you can drop `{}`. So, this should also work `'{ "id":2,"timestamp": "'${a}'","data": "'${D}'"}'`. The trick is to exclude `$a` and `$D` from single quotes.

Comment: https://shellcheck.net/ will help check the syntax of your code for you

Comment: @nobody2 
It still does not work .. I will check the server script maybe there is a mistake there

Answer (score 1):

Don't use echo when calling a command.

You can either refrain from using single quotes. If you choose to do so you need to escape the quotes in your command call:

```
curl -i -k -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{ \"id\":2,\"timestamp\": \"${a}\",\"data\": \"${D}\"}" https:......
```

Or, if you want to use single quotes, you have to do string concatenation, that means end your single quotes before your variable and continue them afterwards (as "nobody" suggested:

```
curl -i -k -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{ "id":2,"timestamp": "'"${a}"'","data": "'"${D}"'"}' https:......
```

If you insist to use echo, you need to use echo's output in your call:

```
curl -i -k -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{ \"id\":2,\"timestamp\": \"$(echo ${a})\",\"data\": \"$(echo ${D})\"}" https:......
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your loop syntax is wrong. `for i in 1 .. 10` will run three times. Once for `1`, once for `..` and once for `10`. To get the numbers between one and ten, you need `for i in {1..10}`. Next, use single quotes inside your `curl` command so you can still use double quotes on the outside so that variables will be expanded. Something like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..10}
do
    a=$(date '+%s')
    D=$(sensors)

    curl -i -k -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        --data "{ 'id':2,'timestamp':$a,'data':$D}" https:......
    sleep 1
done
```

Or, if you need both the tag name and the value to be quoted, use:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..10}
do
    a=$(date '+%s')
    D=$(sensors)

    curl -i -k -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        --data "{ 'id':'2','timestamp':'$a','data':'$D'}" https:......
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: I get the following error 

```
{"message": "Internal server error"}HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway

```
Using a simple syntax like this one does not trigger the error 

```
curl -i -k -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{ "id":"id","timestamp":"data","data":"data"}' 

```

Comment: @Spearitch502 since you haven't given us a valid URL, I have no way of testing and I don't know what format is expected. I also don't know which of my two suggestions you are using. Does the second one fail as well? That one should work since everything is quoted. Finally, please edit your question and add what you tried and the error you get,. As you have seen, it is very hard to add formatting to comments. Just edit the question so we can all see what you tried.

Comment: My bad .. 
I added the URL in the top

Comment: @Spearitch502 and did you try the second option from my answer?

Comment: Yes I tried it but still nothing. Can you try it again? There may be a problem in the server

Comment: @Spearitch502 that has nothing to do with us, I'm afraid. You need to figure out what your server expects, if it is running, if it can receive this sort of POST input etc. The script I have given you will run your command every second, for ten times. Setting up the server to handle the data you send it is up to you.

Comment: ok I will check it then. But another question maybe that could simplify the task. From this output I want the last line
`
# D=$(sensors)

# echo "${D}"

cpu_thermal-virtual-0

Adapter: Virtual device

**temp1:        +50.0 C  (crit = +120.0 C)**
`

Comment: @Spearitch502 are you sure https://dv7knsjzph.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/prod/boxtronic-devices/2/data/ is a URL you can submit data to? It seems to me like it is used to query data. When I simply do 
`curl https://dv7knsjzph.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/prod/boxtronic-devices/2/data/`
I get a json string with parameters "device_id", "data", and "date", indicating that the parameter you are using (timestamp) might be wrong, too.